# how to use my getvalues() method in main to print the list

Tags: java, linked-list

The method does not show any error but I am unable to use it in main method to display the list.

```
    if (userinput.equalsIgnoreCase("push") )
    {   calc.push(value);
        calc.displaylist();
         System.out.println(calc.getValues());
    }
    else if (userinput.equalsIgnoreCase("mult"))
    {  calc.push(calc.mult());
       calc.getValues(); }
```

how to use this method ... instead i used a methos called display list and that works but i need to know how to use my getValues method. both the methods are as below :

```
Double[] getValues()
    {

      Double[] array = new Double[values.size()];
      return values.toArray(array);
    }

    void displaylist()
    {
        for(Double d : values)
          System.out.println(d);
    }
```

Comment: thank you all .... here's how I used my getValues() by assigning it to another variable.. I also learned that I should be more clear in expressing my query ... will certainly try to improvise on that.

Double[] returnValues = calc.getValues();
              for ( int i=0; i<returnValues.length; i++)
              System.out.println(returnValues[i]);

Answer (score 0):

You can use a static method called `toString(Object[])` in the `java.util.Arrays` class.

Answer (score 0):

Well your displaylist() method contains a for-each loop that will iterate over the contents of a collection.  The collection to iterate over is on the right side of the ':'.  You've got a method that returns a collection - specifically, a Double[] - so you can call your getValues() method in place of the collection.

So, try this:

```
void displaylist()
{ 
    for(Double d : getValues()) System.out.println(d);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to understand the question - Let me restate it and see if I got it or not:

1. You have an object that has a `Collection` (probably a `List`) of values called `values`.
2. You have a method, `getValues()`, which returns an array containing all of the values in `values`.
3. You would like to print out all of the values in `values`.
4. You are required (homework?) to use the `getValues()` method when printing out values in `values`.  (If you're not required to use `getValues()`, then I don't see what's wrong with the `displaylist()` method that you already wrote.)
5. You tried to just call `System.out.println()` on the array that you got from `getValues()`, but that just printed something awful like "[Ljava.lang.Double;@39172e08".

Did I get it?

Unfortunately, even with all that, I'm not sure what to suggest because I don't know what you want the printed out version to look like.

Should the values be separated by commas?  If so, Ash's answer will do this for you.
Should each one be on its own line?  If so, Shakedown's answer will do this for you.
Should the values just be separated by spaces?  If so, then you can modify Shakedown's answer to use `print(d + " ")` instead of `println(d)`.